# Trying to highlight on touch with :active pseudoclass in cordova

Tags: css, webkit

I'm trying to highlight the different options of this layout with :active. The problem is that the highlighting doesn't fill the whole content. Here's an image and my CSS and HTML code. Hope you guys can help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ms-appdata: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <h1 style="padding-left: 30px; padding-top: 35px"><img src="img/perro.png" style="float:left;width:42px;height:42px; padding-right: 10px;">Bibliografía APA</h1>
    </head>
<body>
<button onclick="toggle_visibilityone()" style="float: right">[+] 
</button>
<a href="html/libro.html" class="hili" type="button">
<div class="tapp">
LIBRO
</div>
 </a>
 <p id="p1">Un libro debe poseer 25 hojas mínimo (49 páginas), pues 
de 24 hojas sería un folleto y de una hasta cuatro páginas se 
consideran hojas sueltas (en una o dos hojas). Caen dentro de esta 
categoría los e-books y los audiolibros</p>
<hr>
```

here is my CSS

```
   *{
 -webkit-touch-callout: default;               
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;            
 -webkit-user-select: text;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;                
  }

body {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
left: 0%;
top: 0%;
background-color: darkred;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: left;
}

div.tapp:active{
background-color: lightblue;
}


/*Parrafos con descripciones de cada tipo de fuente*/
p{
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
color: black;
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 
 Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
display: none;
animation-name: fadein;
animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes fadein{
0% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}

/*Enlaces del body*/
.hili{ 
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

/*Botones*/
button{
color: black;
margin-right: 10px;
font-size: 10px;
width: 30px;
height: 15px;
outline: none;
background-color: white;
border: none;
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 9px #999;

}

/*Título de Bibliografía APA*/
h1{
position: relative;
background-color: rgb(127, 159, 219);
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 
'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
color: white;
text-align: left;
font-size: 30px;
margin-top: 0px;
height: 70px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 2px;

}
```

And this is how it looks right now: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHDzv.png)

Probably a silly question but I'm trying to learn and I read a lot but I cannot solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The highlighting isn't filling the entirety of the content because the .tapp class is only wrapping the "LIBRO" text.

I would recommend that you apply the `:active` styling directly to the  tag's `.hili` rule in the css or add the additional `.tapp` class to the `<a>` tag.

This would eliminate the need to have the `<div class="tapp">` at all.

So in your html the below would result in your desired outcome:

`<a href="html/libro.html" class="hili tapp" type="button">LIBRO</a>`

### Edit: (with clarity from comments)

Since you are trying to group more items together the `<hr>` tag was not getting included and it has a margin on it. That margin introduced this spacing between the `:active` highlight and the `<hr>`. See the following codepen.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oVBPdw

I would also recommend instead of using an `<hr>` you used border-bottom on the containing div.

Comment: Now only the word "LIBRO" gets highlight. I put the `:active` in `.hili`

Comment: I threw the code into a codepen to dig into this further. As you want to group some of these items together you really should be wrapping all the elements you want grouped with the `<div class="tapp">`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oVBPdw

Comment: I finally solved it, the `hr` margin was preventing the highlighting to expand all over the space. Thanks a lot!